# Java method reference selection narrow type

Tags: java

I wonder why the following code executes the method with Object parameter instead of int:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.function.Consumer bla = new Bla()::shake;
        bla.accept(6);
    }
}

class Bla {
    void shake(int i) {
        System.out.println("shake called with i " + i);
    }

    void shake(Object o) {
        System.out.println("shake called with o " + o);
    }
}
```

Output:

> shake called with o 6

Comment: Hint: dont use raw types ... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Comment: Because `Consumer` is generic, so its parameter is a reference type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is: you are **not** calling that `shake()` method directly.

You are going through the **Consumer** interface!

And that interface says `accept(T t)` where T is an **reference type** generic! But you are using a **raw** type, therefore T turns into Object!
And unfortunately, even with the "correct" generic type Integer, it wouldn't work!

So, yes, the solution, as pointed out first by Eran is to use the `IntConsumer` interface instaed!

Comment: Note that even with `Consumer<Integer>` this would call the object overload since you can do `consumer.accept(null);`.

Comment: @Minn Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are using a raw `Consumer` type, which consumes an `Object`.

Use `Consumer<Integer>`:

```
Consumer<Integer> bla = new Bla()::shake;
```

but you'll have to change the first method signature to `void shake(Integer i)` in order for it to match the `Consumer<Integer>` functional interface.

If you want to consume an `int` with your original `void shake(int i)` method, use an `IntConsumer`:

```
java.util.function.IntConsumer bla = new Bla()::shake;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Consumer bla = new Bla()::shake;
```

is equivalent to

```
Consumer<Object> bla = new Bla()::shake;
```

which is equivalent to (*)

```
Consumer<Object> bla = (Object x) -> new Bla().shake(x);
```

Even if you had specified the intended generic type parameter `Integer`, i.e.

```
Consumer<Integer> bla = new Bla()::shake;
```

it is equivalent to

```
Consumer<Integer> bla = (Integer x) -> new Bla().shake(x);
```

Java [method resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) is a 3-step search:

> 1. Match without using boxing, unboxing, or var-args.
> 2. Match using boxing and unboxing, but no var-args.
> 3. Match all.

Since `shake(Object)` matches in the first step, that is the method used, even for `Integer` type parameter.

To get the `shake(int)` overload, you must either remove the `shake(Object)` overload, or pass a primitive integer value (`byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`), which means you can make it work one of these ways:

```
Consumer<Integer> bla = x -> new Bla().shake((int) x);

Consumer<Integer> bla = x -> new Bla().shake(x.intValue());

IntConsumer bla = new Bla()::shake;    // Recommended solution
```

---

(*) It's not quite equivalent: it's more like:

```
Bla instance = new Bla();
Consumer<Object> bla = (Object x) -> instance.shake(x);
```

This detail is omitted above to focus on method signature resolution.

Comment: There are some differences between using raw types and <Object>. I don't remember offhand, but they come up on SO from time to time.

Comment: @matt Raw types *disable* type parameter matching in the compiler, so e.g. `Consumer<Object>` and `Consumer<Integer>` are not assignment compatible with each other, but `Consumer` is assignment compatible with both, even though all 3 of them are technically compiled to the same bytecode (as a local variable).

Comment: "is equivalent to ... `-> new Bla().shake(x)`" all of these should have `new Bla()` outside the lambda.

Comment: @AndyTurner True. I was trying to keep it simple, focusing on the method signature resolution.

Comment: @Andreas added a footnote.